# Apache Web Server Socket Binding

Tags: sockets, binding

I just started to read some [binding documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html) for Apache HTTP Server. And the very first line "**By default, it listens to all addresses on the machine.**", I found this statement very confusing. What does it mean to be "listening on all addresses"? Definitely they are not going to open all 64000 ports to listen. What are they trying to convey from this?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, *address* would refer to IP addresses, not ports. It doesn't listen on all ports,  it binds (by default) and listens on all IP addresses on the host machine.

Comment: hmm..Apache should probably change the wording here, at least on first look, it sounds very weird and can be horribly misleading for some noobs. . Though they may described it later.